# Url Rewriting in asp.net doesn't work for me

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, web-config, c#-3.0

I am having the below URL and code to change the URL to my custom name in URL. It doesn't return any error but the URL not change.

```
I want the output like this

From : Frm_AdminHome.aspx?MainPage=AdminDashboard&Type=1&Role=r0LnJW8xTBkMh3DZ3ip3Jyt2o98/krx7 
To : Frm_AdminHome/
```

My Webconfig code is here.

```
Frm_AdminHome.aspx?MainPage=AdminDashboard&Type=1&Role=r0LnJW8xTBkMh3DZ3ip3Jyt2o98/krx7 //Query string will be change in every time.

<configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>

<rewriter>

    <rewrite url="~/Frm_AdminHome/(.+).aspx" to="~/Frm_AdminHome.aspx" />
  </rewriter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite is a process where requested url is not changed and another page is delivered. For example, when you need to call /Frm_AdminHome, but execute /Frm_AdminHome.aspx?something without changing the url then you need following *rewrite* rule

```
<rewrite url="^/Frm_AdminHome/?$" to="/Frm_AdminHome.aspx?something" processing="stop" />
```

If you need to change url from Frm_AdminHome.aspx?something to Frm_AdminHome/, this is called redirect and you need to use the *redirect* rule

```
<redirect url="~/Frm_AdminHome.aspx\?.*" to="~/Frm_AdminHome" />
```

This should redirect

```
From : Frm_AdminHome.aspx?MainPage=AdminDashboard&Type=1&Role=r0LnJW8xTBkMh3DZ3ip3Jyt2o98/krx7 
To   : Frm_AdminHome/
```

Refer to http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support for more details.

If configuration above is not working and you do not see any change then it's most likely that UrlRewriter module is not active. For example, if you run in integrated pool mode you might need to add

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <!--<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRewriter" 
        type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

P.S.

For IIS 7+ there is a buit-in [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)

P.P.S.

To get querystring or rawurl use

```
QueryString <%=Request.QueryString.ToString() %> <br />
RawUrl <%=Request.RawUrl %>
```

Comment: This is not working. I got the same URL in my tab Frm_AdminHome.aspx?MainPage=AdminDashboard&Type=1&Role=r0LnJW8xTBkMh3DZ3ip3Jyt2o98/krx7

Comment: The order of attribute was wrong, "url" is for the rewrited url, "to" is for real url. Updated.

Comment: The same URL Displayed

Comment: What IIS, pool mode do you use? if you run in integrated pool mode you might need to add additional config as stated above.

Comment: I am working in local system. I didn't host that. This is my first test only.

Comment: 1) Clear web browser history. Try to rewrite/redirect any other page, e.g. you can find examples of rules in the documentation. Does it work? If not, share your web.config. 2) IIS can be installed on local system too. If you mean you run your site from VS.NET then the default configuration for ASP.NET 4 Web Application template is to use integrated mode for the pool and you will require <add name="UrlRewriter" ... as shown above.

Comment: ya its working. But i can't get the qurey string value in my page

Comment: I got the ouput From : Frm_AdminHome.aspx?MainPage=AdminDashboard&Type=1&Role=r0LnJW8xTBkMh3DZ3ip3Jyt2o98/krx7 
To   : Frm_AdminHome/

Comment: To get querystring use Request.QueryString.ToString() (see updated post). If you cannot get it or you get any error - please share  rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I post my full webconfig without appsettings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52007/discussion-between-user3085540-and-smirnov)